# Counter for adding a nested form in Rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms

I'm using the nested form gem in my Rails 3 app: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form. I'm able to add/remove the "audience fields" in my form. The audience model belongs to the upload model.

What I'd like to be able to do is to count the number of times the audience fields are added in the form. So, for example, the form will initially display "Audience 1" above the audience fields. If I add another audience field, then "Audience 2" will be displayed, and so on.

**application.js**

```
var n = $("div.audiencefields").length;
  $("span").text("Audience " + n);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

**application.js**

```
  $("#removelink").hide().filter(":first-child").show();

  $("div.audiencefields span").each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).text("Audience " + (index + 1));});
```

**nested_form.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {
window.NestedFormEvents = function() {
this.addFields = $.proxy(this.addFields, this);
this.removeFields = $.proxy(this.removeFields, this);
};

NestedFormEvents.prototype = {
addFields: function(e) {
  // Setup
  var link    = e.currentTarget;
  var assoc   = $(link).attr('data-association');            // Name of child
  var content = $('#' + assoc + '_fields_blueprint').html(); // Fields template

  // Make the context correct by replacing new_<parents> with the generated ID
  // of each of the parent objects
  var context = ($(link).closest('.fields').closestChild('input:first').attr('name') || '').replace(new RegExp('\[[a-z]+\]$'), '');


  // context will be something like this for a brand new form:
  // project[tasks_attributes][new_1255929127459][assignments_attributes][new_1255929128105]
  // or for an edit form:
  // project[tasks_attributes][0][assignments_attributes][1]
  if (context) {
    var parentNames = context.match(/[a-z_]+_attributes/g) || [];
    var parentIds   = context.match(/(new_)?[0-9]+/g) || [];

    for(var i = 0; i < parentNames.length; i++) {
      if(parentIds[i]) {
        content = content.replace(
          new RegExp('(_' + parentNames[i] + ')_.+?_', 'g'),
          '$1_' + parentIds[i] + '_');

        content = content.replace(
          new RegExp('(\\[' + parentNames[i] + '\\])\\[.+?\\]', 'g'),
          '$1[' + parentIds[i] + ']');
      }
    }
  }

  // Make a unique ID for the new child
  var regexp  = new RegExp('new_' + assoc, 'g');
  var new_id  = new Date().getTime();
  content     = content.replace(regexp, "new_" + new_id);

  var field = this.insertFields(content, assoc, link);
  $(link).closest("form")
    .trigger({ type: 'nested:fieldAdded', field: field })
    .trigger({ type: 'nested:fieldAdded:' + assoc, field: field });
  return false;
},
insertFields: function(content, assoc, link) {
  return $(content).insertBefore(link);
},
removeFields: function(e) {
  var link = e.currentTarget;
  var hiddenField = $(link).prev('input[type=hidden]');
  hiddenField.val('1');
  // if (hiddenField) {
  //   $(link).v
  //   hiddenField.value = '1';
  // }
  var field = $(link).closest('.fields');
  field.hide();
  $(link).closest("form").trigger({ type: 'nested:fieldRemoved', field: field });
  return false;
}
};

  window.nestedFormEvents = new NestedFormEvents();
$('form a.add_nested_fields').live('click', nestedFormEvents.addFields);
$('form a.remove_nested_fields').live('click', nestedFormEvents.removeFields);
});


// http://plugins.jquery.com/project/closestChild
/*
* Copyright 2011, Tobias Lindig
*
* Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
* and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
*
*/
(function($) {
$.fn.closestChild = function(selector) {
// breadth first search for the first matched node
if (selector && selector != '') {
  var queue = [];
  queue.push(this);
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    var node = queue.shift();
    var children = node.children();
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
      var child = $(children[i]);
      if (child.is(selector)) {
        return child; //well, we found one
      }
      queue.push(child);
    }
  }
}
return $();//nothing found
};
   })(jQuery);
```

**new.html.erb**

```
  <%= f.fields_for :audiences do |audience_form| %>
  <div class="audiencefields">
  <span></span>
  <p>   
    <%= audience_form.label :number_of_people %><br />
    <%= audience_form.text_field :number_of_people %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= audience_form.label :gender %><br />
    <%= audience_form.text_field :gender %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= audience_form.label :ethnicity %><br />
    <%= audience_form.text_field :ethnicity %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= audience_form.label :age %><br />
    <%= audience_form.text_field :age %>
  </p>
  </div>

  <%= audience_form.link_to_remove "Remove this", :id => "removelink" %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add this", :audiences, :id => "addlink" %></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create another answer as comments don't allow formatting code

If [that](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_nested_form.js) is the file you are using then there on lines 69-71 you can find the following code

```
window.nestedFormEvents = new NestedFormEvents();
$('form a.add_nested_fields').live('click', nestedFormEvents.addFields);
$('form a.remove_nested_fields').live('click', nestedFormEvents.removeFields);
```

This bind click events to the add and remove links. In your custom script bind events in the same way. It will be executed once the above is completed. So your code should like this

```
$('form a.add_nested_fields, form a.remove_nested_fields').live('click', function(){

    $("div.audiencefields span").each(function(index, element) {
        //index starts with 0
        $(this).text("Audience " + (index + 1));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This `$("span").text("Audience " + n);` puts Audience n as inner text of each span on your site. I assume you have `span` in `div.audciencefields` in that case the correct code is

```
$("div.audiencefields span").each(function(index, element) {

    //index starts with 0
    $(this).text("Audience " + (index + 1));
});
```

The above will go through each span in div.audiencefields and put correct text into each element.

If you want just add number to the new element you can use

```
var audience = $("div.audiencefields");
audience.last().find('span').text("Audience " + audience.length());
```

The above will find span in the last div with audiencefields class and set the number out of the set.

Comment: yes, I do have the span in the audiencefields div. I changed my code to the edit I posted above. It almost works....when I navigate to the form, it now says "Audience 1" on the first group of audience fields. When I click to add another group, it correctly says "Audience 2", but if I add more groups, it no longer increases the number, it just continues to display "Audience 2". What's going on?

Comment: When do you run the code from edit? You need to run this loop each time you add/remove new fieldset. If you only add new fieldset and don't allow removing you may add my second proposition after each insert.

Comment: I included my form fields above. I definitely need removing, so the second proposition will not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you bind any event to Add this link or just refresh page? If you have any js that handles this you must add the loop into this handler. If you refresh site you need to put the loop in $(document).ready(function(){ loop... });

Comment: No, the site page doesn't refresh for this. I haven't figured out how to bind an event to the "Add this" link. I've added the nested_form.js file for the nested_form gem above. Maybe this will clear things up. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.